# C++ template subclass and multiple inheritance ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14

I have two base classes `A`, and `B`, and a third class `C` that (virtually) derives from both of them.   Each class exposes its own public `shared_ptr` type.

In another class I have two vectors where I want to add objects of type A to one vector, objects of type B to another vector, and objects of type C to both.  This results in three `add` methods, one for each of those three classes.

My problems arise when I try to further derive from `C`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<A>;
    virtual ~A() {};
};

class B {
public:
    using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<B>;
    virtual ~B() {};
};
 
class C : virtual public A, virtual public B {
public:
    using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<C>;
    virtual ~C() {};
};

class D : virtual public C {
public:
    virtual ~D() {};
};

class Test {
protected:
    std::vector<A::shared_ptr> vecA;
    std::vector<B::shared_ptr> vecB;

public:
    void add(const A::shared_ptr& o) {
        std::cerr << "in A" << std::endl;
        vecA.push_back(o);
    }

    void add(const B::shared_ptr& o) {
        std::cerr << "in B" << std::endl;
        vecB.push_back(o);
    }

    void add(const C::shared_ptr& o) {
        std::cerr << "in C" << std::endl;
        vecA.push_back(o);
        vecB.push_back(o);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto c = std::make_shared<C>();
    auto d = std::make_shared<D>();

    Test t;
    t.add(a);
    t.add(b);
    t.add(c);
    t.add(d);
}
```

This doesn't work - the resolution of which version of `add` to call cannot be determined:

```
test.cc:62:7: error: call to member function 'add' is ambiguous
    t.add(d);
    ~~^~~
test.cc:34:10: note: candidate function
    void add(const A::shared_ptr& o) {
         ^
test.cc:39:10: note: candidate function
    void add(const B::shared_ptr& o) {
         ^
test.cc:44:10: note: candidate function
    void add(const C::shared_ptr& o) {
         ^
```

I do have the option of simply passing my `C` object separately to both `Test::add(const A::shared_ptr&)` and `Test::add(const B::shared_ptr&)` because in reality the `B` version of `add` has additional parameters that resolve the overload but I would prefer that the caller not have to remember to do this.

Is this ambiguity resolvable?    My target environment constrains me to C++14.

Comment: please post real code. `cls::add(const A::shared_ptr& o)` is missing a return type and all aliases are private.

Comment: Can you [edit] this question to include a [mre] program that exhibits this problem?

Comment: i failed to make it fail :/ https://godbolt.org/z/sK61Tr

Comment: Worked on my machine.  I think the bug is in the code not provided.

Comment: OK - working on it - it turns out that the issue is when I have a further class `D` derived from `C`, and then try to call `add` with a shared pointer to one of those.

Comment: Well, a shared_ptr<D> isn't a shared_ptr<anything else>. You may need to pointer cast it.

Comment: Why don't you add a into `D` a `shared_ptr` member type and then add `void add(const D::shared_ptr& o) ` like you've done with `C`?

Comment: @NathanOliver because the `Test` class is really a library and there's an unknowable number of possible subclasses of A, B and C that the library should be agnostic to.   `A` and `B` represent orthogonal features that are either standalone, or sometimes combined.   Call them "traits", if that helps (I'm aware of the term but not familiar enough with their use in C++ to know if that might provide a solution instead of multiple inheritance).

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't a problem with raw pointers (https://wandbox.org/permlink/u12WIaINyE3fsIUa). The standard derived-to-base conversions sequences rank based on the length of inheritance chain. Smart pointers can't mimic that easily unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard derived-to-base conversion sequences take the length of the inheritance chain into account when ranking conversion sequences, a close base would be deemed a better conversion sequence than a one that is further up the inheritance chain. And that in turn affects pointers and references too!

Sadly, since smart pointers are user defined types, they cannot benefit from this behavior. All three overloads are viable via a (valid) user defined conversion. And the "ranks" of the individual bases don't affect the ranking of the overloads.

But that doesn't mean we can't re-introduce the ranking impose by a derived-to-base conversion. We just need to do so via another argument. And by employing tag-dispatch, we can do just that.

We can define a helper utility type:

```
template<int n> struct rank : rank<n - 1> {};
template<>      struct rank<0> {};
```

For any `0 <= i < j <= k`, the conversion sequence of `rank<k> -> rank<j>` will always be deemed better than `rank<k> -> rank<i>`. So, if we make your overload set inaccessible, and rank them explicitly:

```
protected:
    void add(const A::shared_ptr& o, rank<0>) { /*...*/ }
    void add(const B::shared_ptr& o, rank<0>) { /*...*/ }
    void add(const C::shared_ptr& o, rank<1>) { /*...*/ }
```

We can then expose another overload in the form of a function template:

```
public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(const std::shared_ptr<T>& o) {
        return add(o, rank<10>{});
    }
```

It mainly just forwards to one of the protected overloads, but it adds another argument. A rank tag. This will affect overload resolution too. Even though all three `add` overloads are viable, the derived-to-base conversion of `rank<10>` will affect the choice of best one.

[Here it is live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mH9sMA1DmVkjVH4D).

Comment: the `10` could be any number `>=1`, right? Or is there a reason you didnt make it the default, and `return add(0,rank<>{});` ?

Comment: It can be any number `>=1` (well, not exceeding the implementation's recursive template instantiation limit). I just use an arbitrary "decent" number to spare myself a bit of work if more overloads are added to the set with `rank<2...10>` (how many overloads is too much, though!?). There might be a smarter way of handling it (Reflection TS!?), but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: ok get it, when you add overloads with rank `11...20` you only have to change the class definition not the `rank` template.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - Yup, exactly. Depending on one's preference, `rank` may be a utility pulled from a common meta-programming header one has laying around, and not written ad-hoc. So a default would probably not be appropriate at all.

Comment: Thanks - impressive work!  I've updated my code to use this and it works.   Now I just have to actually grok it properly...